# Ubuntu 12.04 stopped recognizing my BenQ monitor and reduced resolution to 1024x768

Tags: 12.04, resolution, monitor

A few days ago I installed Ubuntu 12.04 32bit Desktop. It recognized my hardware without a problem (at least that I know of) and all worked fine.
I left my system running (it is at work) through the night because it is also working as a database server and when I came today to work the resolution was `1024x768` (the monitor recommends `1920x1080`) even though in the `Display` section of the `System Settings` it was recognized as `BenQ`, and no higher resolution was offered. After a restart, the monitor name changed from `BenQ` to `Unknown`. This is a desktop computer. I also installed `gtk-redshift` and `f.lux`.

I checked `Additional Drivers` to see if there is something I can install but it didn't find anything. I tried to Google it but I didn't find anything about a monitor stopping being recognized after it was already working. I did enable some PPAs yesterday, namely `webupd8`, `mozillateam/thunderbird-stable` and some other, and I also followed the instructions to patch the `NotifyOSD` to be more friendly:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:leolik/leolik 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
pkill notify-osd
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

I now purged both `caffeine-developers` and `leolik` PPAs in the hope it will help, but no change. Has there been a change in the packages that could introduce this problem?
Any help will be very appreciated :-)

Omri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to get the [edid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) data from your monitor. This can be done with the [get-edid](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/get-edid.1.html) command

```
$ sudo apt-get install read-edid
$ get-edid | parse-edid
```

Did you change your video cable? Some old vga cables do not have the data wire (a wire not used to transmit video signals, but only to interchange data between the computer and the monitor). Maybe that wire got broken if somebody pulled strong from the cable.

You can try to change your video cable, too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :)
Just before reading the answer I realized that the embarrassing solution is that the cable wasn't connected all the way, and as a result Ubuntu stopped getting the data for the screen.
I guess this is a good lesson to check before posting. I didn't know it can have this effect...

Answer (score 0):

Omri, after upgrading to 12.10 my BenQ monitor was not detected any more. I could solve this issue through removing my previously installed proprietary graphics driver ...

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx
```

... and using the default open-source driver.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak
```

(source: http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Lucid_Installation_Guide#Removing_the_Driver)